# How do I Watch full details for each table row with ASP.NET Core and Html Modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a project with ASP.NET Core and I have this My Profile page.

[image: My Profile Page]

So when the details button is clicked I want to show full details for that reservation, let's say I'm gonna send an ViewModel to this view with all datas(all reservations with full details), now the way I wanna show the full details is with Modal.

[image: Full Details Modal]

Like this. How can I achieve this with asp.net core?

Comment: That's a common use case and there are a lot of blog post and SO questions about general approaches. How do you plan to implement it and where do you have questions?

Comment: you can use a separate page to show Full details and open that page as a modal popup onclick of a hyperlink from the grid using jQuery or onclick event and pass querystring to new page.  - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/open-a-new-web-form-in-the-model-popup-of-Asp-Net-applicatio/

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I'm trying to do it with mvc and without api if I can,so I'm gonna send a model to this view the list of reservations, each reservation will have an rental, return object and the other part is confusing me, I don't really know what to do next cause I never tried js before. What I have to do is filter reservations with an reservation ID and based from ID I will populate the modal.

Comment: @Laxmikant Do you mean like an Iframe?

Comment: @G3n1t0, not iframe, you can have a webform.aspx that will be shown as modal popup

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this as an answer, because it's too much text for a comment.

You want to show just a single item as a popup. To do so, you have multiple general approaches:

### Render everything server side and hide what you don't need

In the end, each popup is just HTML. Typically a `<div>` element. So one option is, to render all popups in your razor view and simply hide them all with CSS. Now you can add a css class to make one of them visible.

```
MyView.cshtml

@foreach(var reservation in Model.Reservations)
{
    <div click="document.getElementById('@reservation.id').style.display='block';">
       reservation list item
    </div>
    <div id="@reservation.id" style="display:none">reservation details</div>
}
```

You would encapsulate parts in js functions and reservation.id might not be the right property for an HTML id attribute, but I guess you've got the idea.

### Render only list and fetch HTML fragments

Here you render the list only, then you use javascript to load an HTML fragment from the server.

```
  MyController.cs
  
  getReservationDetails(Guid reservationId) {
     var reservation = load(reservationId);
     // popup html only, no layout, no body tag, ...
     return View(reservation);
  }
```

In your list, you'll need a js function that passes the reservationId as URL parameter and shows thre response (the reservation details) in your popup. Pls see below for some common JS frameworks that provide modals.

### Pass reservations as data to javascript and render client side

Here you pass all your reservations to javascript as data. Then you can create the popup in JavaScript

```
   <script>
      const reservations = [{ ... reservation as json }, { ... }];
      
      function showReservation(index) {
         // render and show in JS
      }
   </script>
```

See [How to get JSON object from Razor Model object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344089/how-to-get-json-object-from-razor-model-object-in-javascript). Example lib to render HTML with javascript: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

### Fetch details as data

Here you create

- An action that returns reservation details for single reservation. It accepts an URL parameter `reservationId` and returns the details as JSON.
- JavaScript function that accepts reservation id, loads data from server and renders the data as popup

See e.g. [How to return a Json from a .Net Core Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383719/how-to-return-a-json-from-a-net-core-web-api)

## Links

### Modals

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals
- https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

### Misc

- https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rendering-views-in-javascript

This is just a starting point. You could think about which option is right for you, try it and then continue in a new SO post, if you have problems with the details.